# In Entity Framework - Code First Approach need to do Delete operations between the Reference tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following two tables (where `entityid` in Table 2 is a foreign key to Table1):

- Table1 { entityid, username }
- Table2 { id, entityid, firstname, lastname.... }

When I perform a delete operation on Table 2 using EF 6, I want the entry in table1 to also get deleted if there is no further reference available in Table2.

By using this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SigODEntity>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.SigODs)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I am able to perform the delete on table1 which would delete the child entries in Table2.

But I want that to happen opposite way as well. Is there any direct way to do that in Entity Framework?

Comment: No. It would make the deletion of a single child record an expensive operation. EF would have to check the existence of the FK value in other entities of the same type. Also, it would increase the chances of errors, because parents may have other references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to perform deletion, as u need. Because you alredy mention the relation from `Table1 → Table2`.

You have to use a loop (foreach) which mention all entrys state in Table2 as Deleted (may be with condition), and the same time you have to check state of entrys in Table2 (*optional, depends on your scenario, if you are using any condition for Table2 deletion, then there will be some data which are not deleted*). If all entry's state in Table2 are `Deleted`, then change the EntryState of Table1 data also as `Deleted` and save

db.SaveChanges()

Comment: Thanks !!! for now to do the Deletion of the parent key I am checking that if no child element present then only delete the parent.